# Linking textures to models from an .fbx file

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, import, .fbx

I am a **newbie**, I downloaded the following model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/2002-spiderman-sam-raimi-9d5d173428d2481ea4a54f3d8b41beda

It is a **Spider-Man model with its textures**, the problem is that it is in **fbx** format, and when I import it to Blender, it **doesn't show the textures**, so from what I understood I have to link myself the textures to each part of the model.

**My doubt is** that I don't know how to link N, S and AO textures. Also I don't understand why there are two models of spider web, lens and lens edges, I guess to apply a texture to each model, I'm quite lost.

I linked texture D through diffusion, I think I did well.

---

Everything I'm learning is based on consulting Blender Exchange, the Blender subreddit and YouTube. It's a new world for me.

Comment: I don't believe this is your fault at all, but rather largely the uploader of the SPIDERMAN model is at fault. The file structure of the original download ZIP file is zipped 2 times more than it should be, which in turn is causing file path chaos. I don't think the model was even exported with properly setup material nodes in the first place.

Comment: I wanted to **try with another one**, and I downloaded the following model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/spider-man-3-the-new-goblin-glider-2007-cf7af32d49aa4969b9569859d7b6acbe

This one unlike the previous one, inside the source folder was the .fbx file, I imported it, and **the textures are not displayed either.**